# Make ReadOnly Textbox Non-Selectable

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, readonly

I have a form with a textbox that has an attribute of read-only.  This isn't a big deal but I thought I would ask, so is there a way to make that textbox so that the user cannot select it and put their cursor in it?

The disabled attribute does that, but then that textbox doesn't get submitted with the form.

Is there a js/jquery solution for this?

**SNIPPET**

---

```
<form>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control clear-textbox create-form-txtbox time-txtbox", @readonly = "readonly" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

---

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ahh that works. thank you, post as answer and I will accept

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have used Stephen's comment as an answer and it works.

I have created a hidden input field to submit to the server, but the user will only see the disabled textbox with the value that that hidden input field is holding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Its working for me.
Replace  @Html.EditorFor with this control.

```
<input type="text" value="@Model.Time" id="Time" name="Time" class="form-control" readonly />
```

Comment: That is what renders on the page when using @Html.EditorFor

Answer (score 0):

Use   inline `onkeydown="return false;"` attribute

or if you want a javascript solution

```
$('#someId').keydown(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```