# jQuery Validator Not Working for DropDownList

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate

I have two dropdownlists:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Operation: <span class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></span></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Operation, ViewBag.Operation as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
            <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Operation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="COAType-div">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">COA Type: <span class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></span></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.COA_Type, ViewBag.COA_Type as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
            <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.COA_Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`COA_Type` does not have a `Required` Data Annotation in the model because, if `Operation`'s value is 2 then that is the only time I want `COA_Type` to be required.. but if `Operation` is anything but 2.. then it does not have to be required.

```
var onLoadValue = $("#Operation").val();
if (onLoadValue === "2") {
    $("#COAType-div").show();
} else {
    $("#COAType-div").hide();
    $("#COA_Type").val("");
}

$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        COA_Type: {
            required: function() {
                if ($("#Operation").val() === "2") {
                    console.log("tttt"); // for testing.. to see if it worked. Obviously not working
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        e.preventDefault();

        var newUrl = redirectUrl + "?aId=" + aId + "&date=" + date;


        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: infoGetUrl,
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                toastr.options = {
                    onHidden: function () {
                        window.location.href = newUrl;
                    },
                    timeOut: 1500
                }
                toastr.success("Successfully Edited.");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var status = capitalizeFirstLetter(textStatus);
                toastr.error(status + " - " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I have tested.. and made the `Operation` val equal 2.. and the `COA_Type` ddl is not being validated..

How do I validate this?

**UPDATE**

Instead of putting the rules right below `validate`.. I rewrote it this way:

```
$("form").validate({
    submitHandler: function () {

        var newUrl = redirectUrl + "?aId=" + aId + "&date=" + date;


        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: infoGetUrl,
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                toastr.options = {
                    onHidden: function () {
                        window.location.href = newUrl;
                    },
                    timeOut: 1500
                }
                toastr.success("Successfully Edited.");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var status = capitalizeFirstLetter(textStatus);
                toastr.error(status + " - " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});

$("#COA_Type").rules("add",
{
    required: function () {
        if ($("#Operation").val() === "2") {
            console.log("tttt");
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Now, the `console.log("tttt");` is being hit and when I click submit.. the `COA_Type` DDL is being outlined in red if it is null bc of the `input-validation-error` but the form is still submitting.  Also, when I check the console about the `"tttt"` I am getting 2 instances of it.. so in the console it looks like:

```
tttt
tttt
```

Comment: Use a conditional validation attribute so that you get client and server side validation out of the box (e.g. a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]`). But you have other issues with your code including that you cannot use the same name for the property your binding to and the `SelectList` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/will-there-be-any-conflict-if-i-specify-the-viewbag-name-to-be-equal-to-the-mode/37162557#37162557))

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that existed! Thanks so much that worked!

Comment: @StephenMuecke If you want to post that as an answer I will accept! I also changed the property names of my Viewbags so they don't match the actual domain property name

Comment: You mean like I did on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634491/make-readonly-textbox-non-selectable/43645612#43645612). Feel free to add your own answer.